Can't change URI port by filter Spring Cloud gateway
The user makes a request to the gateway, then based on either cookie or header the gateway takes the backend port (depending from 'cnpj' value in request) from a repository and then maps the request to localhost:that_port
`@Configuration
public class Balancer {
@Autowired
private AssinanteRepository assinanteRepository;

@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("dynamic_route", r -> r.path("/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.filter((exchange, chain) -> {
                        // Captura o CNPJ do cookie
                        String cnpj;
                        HttpCookie cnpjCookie = exchange.getRequest().getCookies().getFirst("cnpj");
                        if (cnpjCookie != null) { // Se o usuário está autenticado
                            cnpj = cnpjCookie.getValue();
                        } else { // Quando o usuário loga
                            cnpj = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("cnpj");
                        }
                        // Busca a porta correspondente no banco de dados
                        Integer portaBackend = assinanteRepository.findById(cnpj)
                                .map(assinante -> assinante.getApiPORT()).orElse(null);
                        // Verifica se a porta foi encontrada
                        if (portaBackend != null) {
                            // Define a nova URI do backend
                            String uri = "http://localhost:" + portaBackend + exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath();
                            // Altera a URI da requisição
                            ServerHttpRequest newRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().uri(URI.create(uri)).build();
                            exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR,newRequest.getURI());
                            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build());
                        } else {
                            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("CNPJ não encontrado"));
                        }

                    }
                    ))
                    .uri("http://localhost:9998")
            ).build();
}

}`
The problem is the request is always redirected to http://localhost:9998 even if if (portaBackend != null) is raisen
I tried to use no://op but not worked
By debugger I still see the "old" port on this property:
debugger
